# PostgreSQL:update column with dates and return values

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, time, where-clause

I have a table:

For example current date 04/02/2020

```
  id   |   last_update   | update_frequency(days)
--------------------------------------------------
   1    |   01/02/2020   |   2
   2    |   01/02/2020   |   1
   3    |   01/02/2020   |   5
```

I would like to make a single query that will return ids to update.

```
   id   |
---------
    1
    2
```

Comment: So you want to update or select ids to update? There is a mismatch between title and the question itself.

Comment: @Ruslan . . . Please explain the rules for returning the rows you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select id
from table_name
where extract('day' from (last_update - current_date)) >= update_frequency
```